# every orbits have same dimension?

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

For a group G and a set X, let G acts on X.
Then we can consider G-orbits.
Every G-orbits have same dimensions?
And then, dimension of G\X is same as $dim(X) - dim(G-orbits)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking of dimension and so the groups are not abstract, some geometric/differential  structure must be there.  Take $GL(n)$ and look at its action on itself by conjugation. Some orbits are singletons (centralizer element. The scalar matrices). So these  have dimension 0.  Whereas orbit of a diagonal matrix with distinct entries will have different dimension..

Comment: Then how to calculate the dimension of quotient space?

Comment: This needs a course. Because it is a theory.  Things get tricky because some orbits need not be closed. And two different orbits have closures that intersect. In a large open dense set orbits might behave well. If you are studying this in the context of algebraic geometry look at books on Geometric Invariant Theory.

Comment: hmm.... can you recommend basic book?? (introduction book?) for geometric invariant theory? I cannot find proper book... I'm undergraduate 4th year students.....

Comment: Books by Newstead or Dolgachev might be easier than the celebrated one by Mumford. That is if your interest are in algebraic geometric and quotients there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from P Vanchinathan is correct, but you might benefit from a simpler counterexample to the "same dimension" idea. Let $X$ be the Euclidean plane, and let $P$ be a specific point in it (for example, the origin, if your plane comes with coordinates). Let $G$ be the group of rotations of $X$ about $P$ (also known under the fancy name $SO(2)$). Then most of the orbits are the circles with center $P$, and these orbits all have dimension $1$, but there is one orbit consisting of just the single point $P$, and it has dimension $0$.  (Given this counterexample, you can probably produce even simpler ones on your own.)